# Append list in JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to append a list with new names in a json file.

JSON structure:

```
{
    "users": [
        "User1",
        "User2",
        "User3"
    ]
}
```

I have tried this:

```
with open('data/users.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    user_list = json_data["users"]
 with open('data/users.json', 'w') as json_file:
    user_list.append(name)
    json.dump(user_list, json_file)
```

But it turns out like this:

```
["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4"]
```

Why and how do I fix it?

Comment: You're dumping the wrong thing: `json.dump(json_data, json_file)`

Comment: Nothing to explain, you were just dumping the wrong thing

Comment: Is it because you are adding the data as a `list`, whereas the JSON data is more like a `dictionary`?

Comment: @Adriano There can be just as many lists as dictionaries in JSON, they just make accessing the data more cumbersome. But that doesn't in itself make them any less valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the whole data dictionary, not just the list

```
with open('data/users.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    json_data["users"].append(name)
with open('data/users.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_data, json_file)
```